# How to collect String[][]?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am new with Stream API in Java 8 and try to Collect String[][].

I want to split `Fred:Corwill;Wilfred:Corwill;` to `[[Fred,Corwill],[Wilfred,Corwill]]`
but this code doesn't work.

```
public static String meeting(String s) {
    String[][] = Arrays.stream(s.split(";")).map(str -> 
    str.split(":")).collect(String[][]::new);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `collect` use `toArray`:

```
String[][] array =
    Arrays.stream(s.split(";")).map(str -> str.split(":")).toArray(String[][]::new);
```